# Weird exception while using contains() method

Tags: java, spring, collections, el

I'm building a web application using Spring MVC framework.

I have some controller which adds some attributes (users belonging to the same team) to my view, as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/friends", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showFriends(Principal principal) {
       ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("friends");

       User currentUser = userService.findUser(principal.getName());

       // this method returns a Collection<long> of userIds from users that belong to a given team
       Collection<long> userIds = findUsersFromTeam(currentUser.getTeam());

       mav.addObject("users", userIds);
       mav.addObject("currentUser", userService.findUsers();
       return mav;
    }
```

And, in my "friends.jsp" file, I do the following test:

```
<c:when test="${users.contains(currentUser.id)}">
```

Which throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.ArrayList.contains(java.lang.Long)
```

However, `ArrayList` class implements `contains(Object o)` method. What's wrong?

Comment: My guess: `users` is an `ArrayList<User>` and not an `ArrayList<Long>`. If it's like this, you should use `users.contains(currentUser)`

Comment: I'd be happy if you were right, but unfortunately the data types match.

Comment: Generics don't work with primitives. Do you actually have a `Collection<Long>`?

Comment: Also, this is just a result of how EL parses expressions and generates reflective code.

Comment: What does ` userService.findUsers()` return ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a just a result of how EL parses method expressions and how reflection works

```
${users.contains(currentUser.id)}
```

It gets the type of `users`, `ArrayList`, and the type of `currentUser.id`, `Long`. It then uses reflection to get a method named `contains` with a parameter of type `Long` on the type `ArrayList`. It doesn't find one because one doesn't exist. Remember, reflection does not apply inheritance hierarchy checking on parameter list elements.

So even though there is a `ArrayList#contains(Object)`, there is no `ArrayList#contains(Long)`. It therefore fails.

Don't use basic EL for this. Write your own EL function or do the logic in your handler method.